# My program is segmentation faulting but it ran before I implemented polymorphism

Tags: c++, list, polymorphism

This my program that let you add a student or a faculty person into a list. Whenever the function addHead() and addTail() is called the program would crash after line 307 or 325

this is the base class

```
class Person
 {
    private:
        string name, title, department;
    public:
        Person *next, *prev;
        // Constructor & Destructor
        Person()
        {
            name = "";
            title = "";
            department = "";
        }

        Person(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment)
        {
            name = nName;
            title = nTitle;
            department = nDepartment;
        }

        ~Person(){};

        // Setters
        void setName(string nName)
        {
            name = nName;
        }

        void setTitle(string nTitle)
        {
            title = nTitle;
        }
        void setDepartment(string nDepartment)
        {
            department = nDepartment;
        }

        // get-ers
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        string getTitle()
        {
            return title;
        }

        string getDepartment()
        {
            return department;
        }

        virtual void printAll()
        {
            printf("%s is a %s in the %s department \n", name.data(), title.data(), department.data());
        }

};
```

This is the 2 derived class

```
class Student: public Person{
    private:
        struct Date gradDay;
        string minor, extraC;

    public:
    
        Student(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment, int m, int d, int y, string nMinor, string nExtraC)
            : Person(nName,nTitle,nDepartment)
        {
            gradDay.month = m;
            gradDay.day = d;
            gradDay.year = y;
            minor = nMinor;
            extraC = nExtraC;
        }
        ~Student(){};

        // Setters
        void setDate(int m, int d, int y)
        {
            gradDay.month = m;
            gradDay.day = d;
            gradDay.year = y;
        }

        void setMinor(string nMinor)
        {
            minor = nMinor;
        }

        void setExtraC(string nExtraC)
        {
            extraC = nExtraC;
        }

        // Getters
        Date getDate()
        {
            return gradDay;
        }

        string getMinor()
        {
            return minor;
        }

        string getExtraC()
        {
            return extraC;
        }

        // This function finds the number of months until graduation
        int monthTilGrad(int month, int year)
        {
            int x = month + year*12;
            int y = gradDay.month + gradDay.year*12;

            return y - x;
        }

        void printAll()
        {
            Person::printAll();
            printf("     They minor in %s and will graduate on %d/%d/%d. \n     Extracurricular Activities: %s\n",minor.data(), gradDay.month, gradDay.day, gradDay.year, extraC.data());
        }

};

class Faculty: public Person{
    private:
        Date startDate;
    public:
        Faculty(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment, int m, int d, int y)
            : Person(nName,nTitle,nDepartment)
        {
            startDate.month = m;
            startDate.day = d;
            startDate.year = y;
        }

        ~Faculty(){};

        // Setters
        void setStartDate(int m, int d, int y)
        {
            startDate.month = m;
            startDate.day = d;
            startDate.year = y;
        }
        
        // Getters
        Date getStartDate(){
            return startDate;
        }

        void printAll()
        {   
            Person::printAll();
            printf("     They started working here on %d/%d/%d\n", startDate.month, startDate.day, startDate.year);
        }
};
```

This is the list that I made

```
class list_c{
    protected:
        Person *Head, *Tail;
    public:
        void addHead(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment, int m, int d, int y, string nMinor, string nExtraC);
        void addTail(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment, int m, int d, int y);
        void remove(string name);
        void deleteAll();
        void search(string name);
        void printAll();
};
```

These 2 functions are the problematic ones. they're suppose to add a new student object to the head of the doublylinked list and a faculty object to the tail of the list

```
void list_c::addHead(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment, int m, int d, int y, string nMinor, string nExtraC)
{     
    cout<<"in addHead()\n";
    Person *newStudent = new Student(nName,nTitle,nDepartment,m,d,y,nMinor,nExtraC);

    cout<<"before iff\n";
    if(Head)
    {
        Head = newStudent;

    } else{
        cout << "in else\n";
        Head->prev = newStudent;
        newStudent->next = Head;
        Head = newStudent;
        Head->prev = NULL;
        cout << "end of else\n";
    }

    cout<<"exiting addHead()...\n";
}

void list_c::addTail(string nName, string nTitle, string nDepartment,int m, int d, int y)
{   
    Person *newPerson = new Faculty(nName,nTitle,nDepartment,m,d,y);
    if(Tail == NULL)
    {
        Tail = newPerson;

    } else{
        Tail->next = newPerson;
        newPerson->prev = Tail;
        Tail = newPerson;
        Tail->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Thank in advance y'all!!

Comment: If you catch the crash in a debugger, where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables at that point?

Comment: By the way, `if(Head) { Head = newStudent; }` looks *very* wrong. And quite the opposite of what's expected. And the `else` branch for that is probably where the crash happens.

Comment: You need a virtual destructor for `Person` (sorry, I overlooked myself first, my bad).

Comment: Not to mention that the `Person` constructor doesn't initialize the `next` and `prev` pointers, meaning they will have *indeterminate* values, that might be seen as random or garbage. And most likely not equal to being null pointers. So any dereference of these pointers will lead to *undefined behavior* and quite possible crashes as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the crash happen in addHead() in the line that said:
```
head->next = newStudent;
```
hmm I did not notice the next and prev pointer not being initialized let me try putting that in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
if(Head)
{
    Head = newStudent;

} else{
    cout << "in else\n";
    Head->prev = newStudent;
    newStudent->next = Head;
    Head = newStudent;
    Head->prev = NULL;
    cout << "end of else\n";
}
```

The problem is that you have *reversed* the condition: If you *have* a `Head` node, then replace it with `newStudent`. And if there *isn't* a `Head` node then add `newStudent` into the list.

And in the `else` branch, the `Head` pointer will be a null pointer, and any dereference of it will lead to *undefined behavior* and likely crashes.

The condition should be:

```
if (Head == nullptr)
```

Note that this requires a `list_c` constructor which initialized the `Head` and `Tail` pointers to be null pointers.

Also note that the `addHead` function needs to update `Tail` as well when the list is empty (and the `addTail` function should do the same with `Head`).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out and i have concluded that I have the medical diagnosis of Poo brain. The class List_c that I created doesn't have a constructor and causing me to forget to set Head and Tail to be 'NULL'